# Share const variable between interface implementations

Tags: c#, oop, interface, constants

I have the following example structure:

```cs
public interface IWidget {
    void Draw();
}

public class SmallWidget : IWidget {
    public void Draw() {
        rectangle.Draw(WIDGET_WIDTH, smallWidgetHeight);
    }
}

public class MediumWidget : IWidget {
    public void Draw() {
        rectangle.Draw(WIDGET_WIDTH, mediumWidgetHeight);
    }
}

public class LargeWidget : IWidget {
    public void Draw() {
        rectangle.Draw(WIDGET_WIDTH, largeWidgetHeight);
    }
}
```

The `WIDGET_WIDTH` variable is going to be the same for all implementations of the `IWidget` interface. Obviously I can't define it on the interface.

**Where do I define this `const`?**

Comment: In an abstract class? PS: interface declares a contract, not implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base class with common implementation details for all widgets and derive all widgets from this base class instead of the interface directly. This way all the widgets have to abide by `IWidget` interface and you can define their common behaviour once.

```
public abstract class WidgetBase : IWidget {
    public const int WIDGET_WIDTH = 100;
    public abstract void Draw();
}

public class SmallWidget : WidgetBase {
    public override void Draw() {
        rectangle.Draw(WIDGET_WIDTH, smallWidgetHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: I marked this as the answer because I didn't realize that I could mark an interface implementation as abstract within an abstract class. I have in the past implemented as `class MyWidget : IWidget, WidgetBase` which isn't nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want seem like an abstract class

```
public abstract class Widget {

    public const WIDGET_WIDTH = 123;
    public abstract void Draw();
}

public class SmallWidget : Widget {
    public override void Draw() {
        rectangle.Draw(WIDGET_WIDTH, smallWidgetHeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an abstract base class for this. Personally I would regard that as a little constraining. I'd probably use a static class which decouples things a little more:

```
public static class WidgetConsts
{
    public const int WIDGET_WIDTH = 666;
}
```